# Where is a statement of the purpose of physics.stackexchange?

Tags: support, scope

Where is a statement of the purpose of physics.stackexchange?

Comment: What about the [tour]?

Comment: I clicked your link and found the welcome page statement.  I looked for tour on the Home page but could not find it.  I looked for a statement of purpose on the Home page but could not find it.

Comment: @goedelite what parts of "Physics Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for active researchers, academics and students of physics and astronomy... *With your help, we're working together to build a library of detailed answers to every question about physics, astronomy and astrophysics* are not clear?

Comment: Previous question by OP: [Is the purpose of physics.stackexchange to teach or to provide a stage?](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14054/is-the-purpose-of-physics-stackexchange-to-teach-or-to-provide-a-stage).

Answer (score 9):

The [tour](https://physics.stackexchange.com/tour) (available from the big question-mark symbol at top right) states the following:

> Physics Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for active researchers, academics and students of physics and astronomy. It's built and run by you as part of the Stack Exchange network of Q&A sites. With your help, we're working together to build a library of detailed answers to every question about physics, astronomy and astrophysics.

This is the statement of purpose of the site.

Answer (score 7):

The original purpose for the physics SE was to furnish a place where professional practitioners of the art could get assistance from their peers in solving specific technical problems in their field. Over the years it seems to have also become a place where lay people can pose questions about physics to get help understanding it across a fairly broad range of sub-topics within the field.

Whether or not this evolution in purpose is a good thing has been a topic of debate for as long as I have lurked here (~8 years and counting).

Comment: Your answer is appreciated, but it is not the same as a statement of purpose by the persons now responsible for the forum.

Comment: @goedelite And who are the *"persons now responsible for the forum"*, exactly?